# Finding distance/length after exploding at vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shape-file consisting a road network. I wanted to explode the poly-lines at the vertices which I have manged to do. Prior to exploding I also used the function `round($length,3)` to find the distance of the poly-lines using the field calculator in the attribute table, and this gave the length of each poly-line.

I want to do the same after exploding to find the length of the exploded lines. But this time around I didn't get any values, instead got null values. Any idea how I can find the length of each exploded line?

Comment: By **"exploding the polylines at the vertices"** do you actually mean breaking lines into segments at vertices where lines intersect or what?

Comment: Check the CRS of the output layer after using that algorithm. It is probably in `epsg:4326`

Comment: Yep that's what i mean.

Comment: Are you open/free regarding other approaches that can provide you with an output?

Comment: yea it is in epsg:4326 but before exploding it was the same CRS

Comment: then reproject the layer via `Save As...` and run again `round($length,3)`

Comment: Sure I am open. I am going to use the shape file in different model (Something called Agent based modelling). So i have to see if its a different method, if its still possible to be implemented in that model.

Comment: yeah I tried saving and redoing it. It does give results but issue is its not the length of each segment. What I mean by that is if there was polyline of length 90 and if it was broken at vertices to 3 pieces. They will each have length 90 90 90. Instead of having something like 50 30 10

Comment: When you calculate the new length, did you create a new field or try to update the old one? What format is the field you used for the new calculation?